# How can I find the urdf_tutorial display.launch file

Tags: ros, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am looking for this file in my document but failed.

**urdf_tutorial display.launch**

So how can I find this file in my system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194192/how-can-i-find-the-urdf_tutorial-display.launch--file/) by [sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/20392/sara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you should clarify you question a bit...

I interpret your question a bit, hopefully the answer you expected: Now I assume you can run on your system the following launch

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch
```

Now you would like to know where the display.launch lies in your file system.

Being able to run

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch
```

means there is a  package `urdf_tutorial` (In this case it comes along with installation; but answer is valid for any package). On your system. You can enter

```
roscd urdf_tutorial
```

to navigate to the package folder. Now it is a good practice to put `launch` files in the launch sub folder of the package folder. If the package follows this you should see a `launch` folder when typing

```
ls
```

in the `urdf_tutorial` folder. And when entering the launch folder

```
cd launch
```

and typing

```
ls
```

you should see the `display.launch`.

Addition:

You can also run

```
find -L . -name "display.launch"
```

in the `urdf_tutorial` folder to look for the `display.launch` (in case it is not in the `launch` folder)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1